# Unity 5 How Do I Set Text of Text Component of Input Field

Tags: c#, unity

How do I set the text of the new Input Field's Built In Text UI Object in Unity 5+?

```
 myInputFieldText.text = "Text Value I Want";
```

The code above does not work to set the text inside of a InputField's Text. Thanks

Comment: is the component enabled? where is that code located?

Comment: Yes the component was enabled and the text was being set in `Start()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the Text component of a InputField can be used to easily read the text, but setting the value of the text requires more than just changing the InputField's Text.text. The fastest way to set an InputField's Text's text is actually to go right to the InputField itself and to set it's Text that will automatically update the InputField's text component.

So:

```
myInputField.text = "Text Value I Want";
```

Will also set myInputFieldText.text to the same value